# giving numeric value to telephone keypad

Tags: javascript, math

I am trying to use evaluate the product of the values of the buttons pressed when typing "Programming Challenges are fun". I have defined the keys in each if/else if statement and run a for loop to get the value of each letter.

```
var string = "Programming Challenges are fun".toLowerCase();
var sum = 1;
for (i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
    var letter = string[i];
    if (letter == "a" || "b" || "c") {
        sum = sum*2;
    }
```

When i run the script it just runs through this if statement every time for as many times as the string is long. I showed this by putting document.write(sum) inside my for loop as well.

```
    else if (letter == "d" || "e" || "f"){
        sum = sum*3;
    }
    else if (letter == "g" || "h" || "i"){
        sum = sum*4;
    }
    else if (letter == "j" || "k" || "l"){
        sum = sum*5;
    }
    else if (letter == "m" || "n" || "o"){
        sum = sum*6;
    }
    else if (letter == "p" || "r" || "s"){
        sum = sum*7;
    }
    else if (letter == "t" || "u" || "v"){
        sum = sum*8;
    }
    else if (letter == "w" || "x" || "y"){
        sum = sum*9;
    }
    else if (letter = ""){
        sum = sum;
    }
    document.write(sum);
    document.write("<br>");
};

document.write(sum);
```

Any ideas why it would be doing this? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your problem is that your condition is always fullfilled.

An example:

`if (letter == "a" || "b" || "c")`

split it apart:

- is letter equal to "a" ? -> maybe
- is "b" defined? -> yes
- is "c" defined? -> yes

so it's always true. The correct way would be:

`if(letter == "a" || letter == "b" || letter == "c")`

a more convenient way is to check the ASCII values (check http://www.asciitable.com )

the letter "a" is at 97 and the letter "z" is 122, you want to group them in groups of three letters. By the way you forgot the letters q and z so there is one group more ;)

Here's another approach:

```
var string = "Programming Challenges are fun".toLowerCase();
var sum = 1;

// lower bound
var a = 97;
// upper bound
var z = 122;

for (i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
    // get the ascii value
    var letter = string[i].charCodeAt(0);

    // boundary check
    if(letter >= a && letter <= z) {
        // we remove the lower bound to get a relative position from 0-25 (alphabet has 26 characters)
        // we divide by three and cut off all decimals (parseInt) so a,b,c become 0, d,e,f become 1 etc. 
        // then we add an offset of two so that a,b,c has factor 0+2=2, d e f has factor 1+2=3 and so on...
        var factor = parseInt((letter - a) / 3) + 2; 

        sum *= factor;
    }
}

document.write(sum);
```

you can try it out on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uJGgV/1/

Answer (score 3):

Because `"b"` is a `true` value, so even if the letter is not `"a"` it passes the `if` condition.

Instead, try this:

```
var keys = {
        a:2, b:2, c:2,
        d:3, e:3, f:3,
        g:4, h:4, i:4,
        j:5, k:5, l:5,
        m:6, n:6, o:6,
        p:7, q:7, r:7, s:7,
        t:8, u:8, v:8,
        w:9, x:9, y:9, z:9
    },
    sum = 1,
    string = "Programming Challenges are fun".toLowerCase(),
    l = string.length, i;
for( i=0; i<l; i++) {
    if( keys[string[i]]) sum *= keys[string[i]];
}
document.write("The total is: "+sum);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if (letter == "d" || "e" || "f")
```

and friends should be

```
if ((letter == "d") || (letter == "e") || (letter == "f"))
```

as you want to `OR` not the letters, but the conditions

**Edit:**

@Kolink's answer has much better code, use it. Regard this here as a teacher's answer, not a programmers answer